# Ext.dataview.List not showing items after build

Tags: sencha-architect, sencha-touch-2.1

I'm currently having a wierd issue after build my app. After build using the command `sencha app build package`, one of my list componets just stop working on this minified version of the app.

When I run this app withou minify It work as intended.

Every other list works as intended, also another one that use the same Store.

How do I disable uglify during build? I'm suspecting that It is messing up the application.

```
{
                    xtype: 'list',
                    html: '',
                    id: 'listaProblemas',
                    itemId: 'listaProblemas',
                    margin: '10 0 0 0',
                    minHeight: 420,
                    padding: '0 0 0 0',
                    ui: 'round',
                    width: '100%',
                    layout: {
                        type: 'card'
                    },
                    emptyText: 'Não há problemas definidos',
                    itemTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate', 
                        '<table style="width: 100%">',
                        '    <tr>',
                        '    <td valign="middle" width="5%" align="left">',
                        '      <tpl for="SAP_OMCatalogoFalhaCausa">  ',
                        '           {% if (xindex > 1) break; %}',
                        '             <tpl if="SAP_OMCatalogoFalhaCausa == \'\' || SAP_OMCatalogoFalhaCausa == null">',
                        '                <img alt="" src="app/images/Pendente.png" />',
                        '            </tpl>',
                        '            <tpl if="GrupoCodeCausa == \'REPROVAD\' ">',
                        '                <img alt="" src="app/images/Reprovado.png" />',
                        '            </tpl>',
                        '            <tpl if="GrupoCodeCausa != \'REPROVAD\' && GrupoCodeCausa != \'\' && GrupoCodeCausa != null">',
                        '                <img alt="" src="app/images/Aprovado.png" />',
                        '            </tpl>',
                        '        </tpl>',
                        '    </td>',
                        '    <td width="100%" align="left">',
                        '        {NomeSistema} <br />&nbsp;',
                        '       <img alt="" src="app/images/setahierarquia.png" />',
                        '        <tpl if="NomeParte != \'\' || NomeParte != null">{CodeParte}- {NomeParte}',
                        '        <br />',
                        '            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;',
                        '           <img alt="" class="style2" src="app/images/setahierarquia.png" /> <b>{CodeProblema}- {NomeProblema} </b>',
                        '       </tpl>',
                        '       <br />',
                        '       <br />',
                        '        <tpl if="TextoProblema != \'\' && TextoProblema != null">',
                        '            <p> <b>Descrição do Problema: </b>&nbsp;{TextoProblema} </p>',
                        '        </tpl>',
                        '       <tpl if="Status && Status !== \'\'">',
                        '            <p> <b>Status da Garantia: </b>&nbsp;{StatusDescricao} </p>',
                        '        </tpl>',
                        '        <p> <b>Causas: </b> </p>',
                        '          <tpl if="SAP_OMCatalogoFalhaCausa == \'\' || SAP_OMCatalogoFalhaCausa == null">',
                        '             Não definidas.',
                        '        </tpl>',
                        '       <tpl for="SAP_OMCatalogoFalhaCausa">     ',
                        '           <p>-> {CodeCausa}- {NomeCausa}</p>',
                        '       </tpl>',
                        '    </td>    ',
                        '    </tr>',
                        '</table>',
                        '',
                        '',
                        {
                            disableFormats: true
                        }
                    ),
                    loadingText: 'Carregando....',
                    store: 'SAP_OMCatalogoFalha',
                    allowDeselect: true,
                    onItemDisclosure: true,
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'toolbar',
                            docked: 'top',
                            height: '70px',
                            html: '&nbsp&nbspLista de Problemas',
                            margin: '',
                            padding: '',
                            ui: 'subnav',
                            items: [
                                {
                                    xtype: 'button',
                                    docked: 'right',
                                    height: 60,
                                    id: 'btnProblemaDel',
                                    margin: 4,
                                    iconCls: 'trash',
                                    iconMask: true
                                },
                                {
                                    xtype: 'button',
                                    docked: 'right',
                                    height: 60,
                                    id: 'btnProblemaAdd',
                                    margin: 4,
                                    iconCls: 'add',
                                    iconMask: true
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue! Every other functional list was set as layout property `vbox`. The only list that stop working after building was set as `card`. Changing this, solve the issue.